# git rebase -i HEAD~N --> How to determine N?

Tags: git

I created a pull-request and upstreams wants me to create a single commit.

I know that I can use this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~N

# then pick the first commit, and squash the following commits

git push --force-with-lease
```

But there are many commits, so that I don't know the right number of N immediately.

Is there a way to detect `N` with a one-liner?

Comment: If the branch you're currently rebasing has been branched off `master` as your answer seems to indicate, you don't need to use the `HEAD~N` refspec construct, just use the ref you have : `git rebase -i master`. I'd further argue you might (depending on your specific workflow) not even need interactive rebase here, just `git reset --soft master` and recommit once for all.

Comment: @RomainValeri although I agree, there is a slight risk in resetting directly to `master`, if it changed since you branched off it.

Comment: @TTT I agree. That's why I added "(depending on your specific workflow)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `HEAD~N` simply resolves to a specific commit ID, which you can quickly determine by glancing at `git log` or any UI. Besides, using `N` as the number of commits only works if the commits you wish to rebase are linear. Therefore, if you don't know what `N` is, consider not trying to determine it and just use the commit ID instead.

If you know your branch came off of `master`, you could even view the commit ID without even looking at the log or a UI graph:

```
git merge-base master your-branch
```

Which means in the general sense you could always use (in Git Bash):

```
git rebase -i $(git merge-base master @)
# Note @ is shorthand for HEAD which is your current branch tip
```

Another consideration is you can interactive rebase onto `master` directly:

```
git rebase -i master
```

If your local copy of `master` hasn't changed since you created the branch you are rebasing, then that will be identical to using the `merge-base`. If `master` is now ahead of where you started, then this won't be identical because you are replaying your commits onto a different state, and it's possible you'll have conflicts. Note in this case these are conflicts you'll have to resolve anyway, but some people may prefer to finish the squash first without the possibility of conflicts, and then do another rebase onto a newer `master` to resolve conflicts afterwards. One reason for this is before the squash you may have to resolve conflicts in multiple commits, whereas if you squash first you'll only have to resolve conflicts in the squashed commit(s).

**A faster squash**: in the case where you wish to squash all of your commits down into a single one, it's usually more efficient to use `reset` instead of interactive rebase:

```
git reset --soft <commit-ID-you-started-your-branch-from>
# or without even looking:
git reset --soft $(git merge-base master @)

# now commit
git commit -m "Add new commit message here"
```

Note you could also reset to `master` directly instead of the `merge-base` command above, like [Romain Valeri mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72741600/git-rebase-i-headn-how-to-determine-n#comment128485400_72741600), but you can do this **only if** the `master` branch hasn't changed since you branched off of it. Just in case you're wrong about that I would recommend sticking with either the `merge-base` command or just use the hash of the parent commit of the first commit on your branch.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
git log master.. --oneline| wc -l
```

Comment: I'm guessing the DV is because this doesn't work in the general sense if you have new merge commits.